# Convergence of improper integral by studying this limit

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I have to study the convergence of the integral

$$ \int_1^\infty \frac{\pi/2 - \arctan(\sqrt{x})}{x^\alpha} \, dx$$

using the asymptotic comparison criteria and in order to do it I have to establish for what $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ exists

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} x^{\beta} (\pi/2 - \arctan(\sqrt{x})) = L \ne 0 $$

At the beginning I tried to study

$$ \int_1^\infty \frac{\pi/2 - \arctan(\sqrt{x})}{x^\alpha} \, dx = \int_1^\infty \frac{\pi/2}{x^\alpha} \, dx - \int_1^\infty \frac{\arctan(\sqrt{x})}{x^\alpha} \, dx $$

but then the limit is useless...
can you help me? Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the asymptotics $$\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan y \sim \frac{1}{y}$$ as $y \to +\infty$. Hence your integral is convergent if and only if $$\int_1^{+ \infty} \frac{1}{x^{1/2 + \alpha}} \ dx$$ is, i.e. $\alpha > 1/2$.

Comment: yes $\alpha > 1/2$ is correct. But what about the limit?

Comment: @brt22 With $\beta = 1/2$ you have $$\lim_{x \to \infty} x^{\beta} (\pi/2 -
 \arctan \sqrt x)= \lim_{x \to \infty} x^{1/2} \frac{1}{\sqrt x} = 1$$